# How to control the probablity of an event given a certain number of dice rolls

Tags: javascript, probability

I have a turn based game.  I set a condition on the player that for the next `X` fixed number of turns he/she has a `Y` percentage chance of triggering some other event (say game over).

So say `x = 5` and `y = 80%`.  I need to flip a coin 5 times (maximum) and on **each coin flip**, modify the outcome percentage (between true and false) so that the **combined/average percentage** likelihood of rolling true over all 5 turns is equal to 80%.

If I make each roll 80% chance then that doesn't average to 80% over 5 turns (it is much higher).  So, how to force y % (roughly) given x coin flips?

I am working in JavaScript.

Edit:

From Thiatt suggestion I implement this code below (assuming 0.16 over 5 turn would yield 80%).  In practice it turns out to be close to 68%.

This seems close, but when I implement it comes out closer to 70%:

```
for(var k = 0; k < 20; k++){    
    var totalHit = 0;
    for(var i = 100; i >=0; i--){
            var hit = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            var roll = rollDice(1, 100);
            hit = roll <= 20;
            if(hit){
                totalHit++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    debug('Hit ' + totalHit + '/100');
}
```

Comment: You coudl decide before hand whether the user rolls the right value? First 80% of 1 or 0. Then a random which dice will roll it

Comment: p1+p2+p3+p4+p5=0.8? then p = 0.8/5?

Comment: @Thiatt I think it should be `(p1+p2+p3+p4+p5)/5 = 0.8`

Comment: @Thiatt Maybe post it as an answer, so OP can accept it?

Comment: 80% average probability over 5 turns is not the same as 80% probability of getting true all 5 turns. I think I'm still wrong anyway, didn't think this through that much.

Comment: If this were me, I'd be lazy and  do the 80% pass/fail first, then fake the coin flips after the fact to fit the predetermined result.

Comment: I would recommend you move this to [Math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) since it is more related to maths than it is to implementation of actual code, I am pretty sure your problem is the maths behind it and not the actual code implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My parsing of your question is that, using your example numbers, you want the probability that the user doesn't trigger event Y over 5 turns to be 0.2.  That is, they have a 0.8 chance of triggering event Y at least once (1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 times, not zero times).

You are using a coin so there are two possible events each round.  The probability of not triggering in a single round will be (1-p) where p is the desired probability you are solving for.  Over five rounds you have (1-p)(1-p)(1-p)(1-p)(1-p)=(1-p)^5=0.2, solving for p gives ~0.275 or 27.5%.  If you have a 27.5% chance of triggering Y at each roll, the probability of triggering Y at least once is 80%.

Comment: This is the only correct answer, you beat me to it. In simple terms, it can be explained with this example - If there's a 20 percent chance of rain on Monday, a 20 percent chance on Tuesday, and a 30 percent chance on Wednesday, what's the overall chance that it'll rain during this three-day period? How do you calculate this?

Comment: You take the chance that it won't rain on day one (0.8), multiply by the chance on days two (0.8) and three (0.7). That gives you 0.448. So there is a 44.8% chance it won't rain, which means there's a 55.2% chance that it will rain in that three-day period. [Source](http://ask.metafilter.com/36264/How-to-calculate-average-probability).
In this case, 55.2% is just 80% and rest can be solved algebraically.

Answer (score 0):

Simply let 80% be true:

```
if(Math.random()<0.8) alert("we were the lucky 80%!");
```

Some explanation:

Lets say we roll a dice. If we want to win on 50%, we simply say, that one does win at 1,2,3 and loose at 4,5,6.

```
win=RollDice()<3;
```

The same principle can be used with Math.random. It returns a Number between 0 and 1, so 80% would be 0.8.

Comment: This actually only has a chance of 20% because `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

P = Y/X

For 5 rolls, if each roll has 16% chance of triggering the event, there's an 80% chance that the event will be triggered over 5 rolls.

Or if you want to keep probability 80% through all the remaining rolls:

P(n) = Y/(X-n+1)

So if the first roll is false, there's an 80% chance of getting true on the remaining 4. If the first two are false, there's an 80% change of getting true on the other 3, etc.

Comment: This seems close, but when I implement it comes out closer to 70%:\nfor(var k = 0; k < 20; k++){

   var totalHit = 0;
   for(var i = 100; i >=0; i--){

    var hit = false;
    for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
     var roll = rollDice(1, 100);
     hit = roll <= 20;
     if(hit){
      totalHit++;
      break;
     }
    }
   }
   debug('Hit ' + totalHit + '/100');
  }

Comment: That's because I suck at this, check the top answer ;)